# Cannot select variables from table (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

I have Variable **Names** which stores all column names.

```
Names = {“col 1”, “col 2”, “col 3”}
```

I want to make request like `SELECT $Names FROM MyTable`

Generated SQL: `SELECT 'col 1' FROM MyTable;`
but I got error: Value column must have numeric datatype, column: ?column? type: string value: col 1

When I manually change quotes on double quotes it works but I don’t want to change this every time.
`SELECT "col 1" FROM MyTable;` works.

I tried to use {Names:doublequote} but it also doesn't work. SQL: `SELECT {Names:doublequote} FROM MyTable`

Generated SQL: `SELECT {col 1, col 2} FROM MyTable`
What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I just used version 6.7.3, but 'singlequote', 'doublequote' and 'sqlstring' was added in version 7.0.0-beta1. I'm sorry.